# phpMyAdmin import schema from workbench

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I've made a schema for a database in mySQLWorkbench, I'm trying to then import this into phpMyAdmin, however it is finding a error in my code. I tried several online sql validators which also flag the same error. I'm unable to see the error, nor what could be wrong with my workbench settings.
The start of my schema

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `travelapp` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `travelapp` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `travelapp` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `travelapp`.`Address`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `travelapp`.`Address` (
  `address_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `line_1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `line_2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `street_name` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `town` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `district` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and this is the error I'm getting

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
  `town` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `district` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `p' at line 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the length in:

```
`street_name` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
```

In the above code.
Use this:

```
`street_name` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                      ^^^ give the length
```

The error is here.

Comment: Oh, yup that was the problem, was thinking there must have been something wrong with the export settings D: ....    Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the length of `varchar` field for `street_name`

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE `travelapp`.`address` (
  `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `line_1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line_2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL, -----> Here
  `town` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store.

Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html